# how to apply tint color on tap and reset tint color on release?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

i am newbie in iOS.

i have a horizontal menu bar in collection view .

i want to apply tint color when user tapped .

When user releases finger from button it have to return to old color.

Each button is a cell

below is the gif of menubar generated by swift code

i am trying to migrate below swift code to Objective C

[image]

```
class MenuCell:BaseCell {
// Type of Class UICollectionViewCell
let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = UIImage(named:"home")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
iv.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(91,green:14,blue:13)
}()

// Dont know how to convert below code to Obj C
override var highlighted : Bool {
     didSet {
     imageView.tintColor = highlighted ? UIColor.whiteColor() : UIColor.rgb(91,green:14,blue:13)
   }
}

// Dont know how to convert below code to Obj C

override var selected : Bool {
     didSet {
     imageView.tintColor = highlighted ? UIColor.whiteColor() : UIColor.rgb(91,green:14,blue:13)
   }
}
```

In Objective C, There is no didset method (Type:UICollectionViewCell) showing in autosuggestion

What i tried so far is given below .

```
MenuCell.m // Type is UICollectionViewCell
......
self.menuCellIcon.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"]
                           imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

self.menuCellIcon.tintColor = [UIColor
                               colorWithRed:91/255
                               green:14/255
                               blue:13/255
                               alpha:1];
self.menuCellIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `setHighlighted` / `setSelected`:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    // your tint color code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];
    // your tint color code
}
```

Comment: In your code you set the `backgroundColor` instead of the `tintColor`...

Comment: The icons are `UICollectionViewCell`s? Or `UIButton`s?

Comment: icons are UICollectionViewCell